# Do JS Reference Errors stop runtime thread execution?

Tags: javascript

Since JS normally runs on only one thread, can a reference error from one script block subsequent JS execution as other scripts are evaluated?

Thanks!

Comment: in other words, can one reference error stop an entire js application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate scripts are evaluated separately, so no (unless of course the error in the first script broke something that the second script depended on).

The error itself will only break the current execution of code. Even other code in the same script can continue to function if otherwise unencumbered. (For example event handlers that were bound and were not directly affected by the error.)

Comment: so if an error happens inside, say, an event handler, does that mean that event handler becomes inaccessible? or can subsequent events still invoke it?

Comment: Subsequent events will still invoke it.